# Modify jQuery.AJAX Values Before Send Using Form.serialize() for 'data'

Tags: forms, jquery, serialization

I have a jQuery.ajax() POST request, that runs on button click and has its `data` parameter set to `$(this).parents('form').serialize()`.

There is one Textarea in the form that has a default placeholder, which I would like to replace with a blank value just before the AJAX request is sent. Is it possible to achieve this using the `beforeSend` event of jQuery.ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply manipulate the form data.

```
$.extend($(this).parents('form').serialize(), { textarea_name: "" });
```

If you don't want the value being sent at all, `delete` the property from the object returned by `serialize()`.

Comment: This is not an option in my case, since the code that generates the AJAX request is encapsulated (created on the fly). I only have the option to work with the jQuery.ajax options and not work with the data directly. This is why I stated that, if possible, I would like to do this in the `beforeSend` event.

Comment: @ColorWP.com Use the second argument in `beforeSend()` to manipulate the `data` object using my code as a guide above.